# How to define custom attributes while appending a js file in Zend Framewok?

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, attributes

I am trying to implement content flow in my zf application. And while loading its attributes, it requires one extra attribute to be defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".." load="white"></script>
```

To interprete this using zf, i tried

```
$this -> headScript() -> appendFile("my/path/to/contentflow.js","text/javascript", array("load" => "white"));
```

But its not working.

How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom attribute" - do you mean parameters  in the URL?

Comment: @Pekka, no... I am trying to get `<script type="text/javascript" src=".." load="white"></script>` using zend framework `$this -> headScript() -> appendFile(...);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zend Framework does not allow such random attributes. If you really have to use them, you have to enable them using

```
$this -> headScript() -> setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Nabin. This was really bugging me

Comment: Even the most recent (1.11.12) version does not output the async attribute without calling the setAllowArbitraryAttributes method!  If that isn't allowed, what does ZF consider to be a non-arbitrary attribute?!

Comment: @moonDogDog, `async` is not a  valid attribute for script. `charset`, `type`, `src` and `defer` are the only valid attributes according to HTML 4 Specification.